# Regex to find C# async methods with missing "Async" suffix?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

In C#, one of the conventions for asynchronous methods (those marked with the `async` keyword) is that their names should end with an "Async" suffix:

```
public async Task MyMethod(/* params */) ...         <-- Bad, missing "Async" suffix
public async Task MyMethodAsync(/* params */) ...    <-- Good, as per convention
```

I've been writing a lot of async code lately, and I'm concerned that I may have forgotten to put the "Async" suffix on some methods.

Is there any regex that I can use to find those methods that are marked with `async` but that do *not* have the "Async" suffix? If that's possible, can the reverse be done (ie. find methods that *do* have an "Async" suffix but that are *not* marked with the `async` keyword)?

I would be looking to paste the regex into the "Find In Files" dialog in Visual Studio, if that makes any difference to the answer.

I'm guessing that tools like FxCop, CodeRush or ReSharper may already warn about things like this, however the latter two are not an option given my workplace, and I'd rather not have to install & configure the former if I can accomplish this using a simple regex.

Comment: You could have a unit test that checks this using reflection.

Comment: What do you know about regular expressions? Have you actually made an attempt, or is this merely a "code plz" request?

Comment: FWIW, ReSharper doesn't warn about this.  In fact, when typing the method out, it's auto-suggesting that it should end in `Task`

Comment: @JamesThorpe really? That's wrong and should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @usr [Yup!](http://imgur.com/F0kzESA)  Having said that, it's only following standard behaviour.  [Here's another example](http://imgur.com/hTSZq7W)

Comment: Ah, Smurf naming conventions strike again...

Comment: The benefit of using a tool like FxCop (which I don't know if it does this by default) is that it will catch future problems as well.  The regex may fix your problem today, but doesn't prevent you from doing this all over again.

Comment: @MagnusHoff I certainly don't proclaim to be a regular expression expert! I got as far as finding lines that had `async` followed by a bunch of text then an opening brace. The bit I wasn't sure how to do was check whether the "Async" text before the brace was missing. To be fair I expected someone to have asked this on SO already: I could have put more effort in to find out how to do it myself but at least this way the answer is documented for others in the future.

Comment: @JohnKoerner I take your point, it's just that I don't have time at the moment to install & configure FxCop and deal with the inevitable warnings that it will generate for our codebase. On the to-do list for the future though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here with Regex:

```
(?i)async.*(?<!async)\(
```

It looks for the keyword async and then at a "(" without ("?<!") async before it.

Edit:
Better version. Thx @Andrew

```
Task\s+(\w+(?<!Async))\(
```

This will give you the methods with small written asyncs at the and as well. Furthermore it allows to use find and replace.

Comment: Nice! I would change it to @"Task\s+(\w+(?<!Async))\\(", case insensitive. It also captures the method name so you can replace append and replace "Async".

Comment: Your addition of "Task" wouldn't find `async void`  methods. And (?i) at the start makes it case insensitive. But capturing the method so you can just use find and replace is pretty neat.

Comment: There is no point in finding async void methods.. They can't be awaited so their name shouldn't end in "Async". Sorry, I meant to say case sensitive, that's why I excluded "(?i)".

Comment: @LzyPanda Thanks for that. Apparently this is called a [zero-width negative lookbehind assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion). I've not used those before when doing regex.

Comment: @LzyPanda After trying the regex I noticed that it doesn't work for task methods that return a result, eg. `async Task<int>` and the like. So I ended-up using `Task.*\s(\w+(?<!Async))\(` as the regex instead. It gives a few false positives but I can live with those.

Comment: @StevenRands Try `Task(?:<?\w*>?)\s+(\w+(?<!Async))\(`

Comment: @LzyPanda That's great! I also came up with something for the reverse check (non-async method with "Async" suffix): `(?<!(Task(<.+>)?|await|return))\s+(\w+Async)\(`. It gives a fair number of false positives but that's because it's difficult to tell the difference between a method definition and a method call without context.

Comment: @LzyPanda your regex is by far the fastest and most accurate in comparison to everything else

Answer (score 5):

Here is one that also works for generic methods and methods that return results (potentially using generics again).

```
 async (void|Task(<.*>)?) [^<\(]*(?<!Async)(?:<.*?>)?\(
```

I have tested it against the following patterns:

```
 async void Test()
 async void Test<T>()
 async void Test<T, U>()
 async Task Test()
 async Task Test<T>()
 async Task Test<T, U>()
 async Task<T> Test()
 async Task<T> Test<T>()
 async Task<T> Test<T, U>()
 async Task<T<U>> Test()
 async Task<T<U>> Test<U>()
 async Task<T<U>> Test<T, U>()
```

Comment: This regex mistakenly matched `public async Task<IEnumerable<Entity>> GetMembersByIdsAsync()`

Comment: @Korayem: Which regex engine are you using? I cannot confirm this. The expression matches correctly *without* the "Async" at the end. But it does not match with "Async" at the end. That's the way it should work. See this: https://regex101.com/r/RF7FBL/2

Comment: "Find in files" inside Visual Studio with regex enabled, as per the main question

Comment: @Korayem: I tried your example in Visual Studio 2017 and my suggested regular expression does not match (which is correct), either. I don't think your observation is correct.

Comment: `async void` *shudders*. Can it also tell people not to do that :P

Comment: Hmm, I actually got the same results as @Korayem with it accidentally matching correctly name methods suffixed with Async... VS2019 here, Match Case and Use Regular Expressions on... Even changing the negative look behind to be simpler matches incorrectly in VS... Weird!
`((async )?Task(<.*>)?|async (void|Task(<.*>)?)) [^<\(]*([^Async])(?:<.*?>)?\(`

Tried on .NET Regex tester and both versions behave as expected, could be a VS bug?!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that the culprits are methods that have parameters of generic types... Doesn't happen in .NET Regex Test (online) though, so it's definitely a VS quirk.

Comment: @benmccallum: I also tried it in VS 2017 back then and it behaved correctly - oddly enough. Could it be related to the "Match Case" flag being set? I don't think I was using that...

Answer (score 4):

Good lad, clean code FTW. :) Alongside any other answers, here's how I'd do it through using the `grep` utility:

```
grep '\basync\b' file.cs | grep -v 'Async('
```

the first `grep` finds all lines with `async` in them (as a word) and the second `grep` filters them to just ones without `Async(` in them.